# What does "_" mean in C programming language?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

Recently I am reading linux kernel code and I read this:

```
#define MODULE_PARM_DESC(_parm, desc) \
    __MODULE_INFO(parm, _parm, #_parm ":" desc)
```

I am very confused that why there is a "parm", what is the relationship between "parm" and "_parm"?

Comment: I think that underscore is just part of a naming convention.

Comment: C treats `_` as an alphabetic character, just like `a` or `x` for example.  Anything else is strictly a naming convention.

Comment: `_` is like a letter yet may also begin  various reserve identifiers.

Comment: Apart from the fact that some identifiers starting with `_` are reserved in certain contexts, `parm` and `_parm` are entirely distinct identifiers. There is no more relationship between them than between `parm` and `foo`, or between `parm` and `Parm`. (Obviously the author of the code meant them to appear similar.)